# Can Central Index Keys (CIKs) issued by the SEC be reassigned?

Tags: equities

Suppose company A has CIK 0000012345 and ceases to exist. At some later time, company B registers with the SEC to submit filings.

Is it possible that company B will be assigned the same CIK 0000012345? In other words, are CIKs unique for all time or are CIKs unique at any instant of time?

Comment: how is this related to quantitative finance?

Comment: @Freddy: The quant finance exchange is 'for finance professionals and academics'. Admittedly, this is loosely related but an understanding of CIK mappings is required to make sense of the (quantitative) data offered by the SEC.

Comment: @Freddy This question seems pretty fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in touch with the securities and exchange commission. CIKs cannot be reassigned and are unique for all time. See the excerpt below:

> CIKs are not reassigned or recycled by the SEC -- they are intended to be forever unique.